# How to print the content of a sqlite3 database?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I want the below code to print the content of a database:

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM records")  

    for row in c:
    
        print(c)
```

However, the output is like this:

```
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f982e0dec00>
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f982e0dec00>
```

Comment: c.fetchall() will do

Comment: Don't you want to print `row`?

Comment: @KlausD. yes print(row) did the job!

Comment: @Tarik I tried c.fetchall() but it did not work.

Comment: print(c.fetchall())

Comment: print(c.fetchall()) worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM records")  

    for row in c:
    
        print(row)
```